# JAVA Project, create a display table consisting of 4 rows 11 columns

Tags: java

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
public class lab {

    public static void main(String[] args) { //don't comment this out
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


        String output = "";

        for (int x = 1; x <= 4; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y <= 9; y++)
            {
                output = output + x*y + "  ";
            }
            output = output + "\n";
        }

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,output);
    }
}
```

//I need to create a program to display a table showing

```
1 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
2 0 2 4 6 8 10 12 14 16 18
3 0......................
4 0.......................
```

and so far my program starts from 0. I was wondering How I would code it to start from the first column of 1,2,3,4 and then the second column of 0,0,0,0

Comment: oh, I don't know what happened to the example.. how do I fix it? I was trying to create a table of 4 rows and 11 columns.

Comment: Add `output += x + "  ";` before second for-statement.

Comment: Thankyou saka1029! it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:

```
public class test  {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String output = "";

        for (int x =1; x <= 4; x++) {
            output += x + " ";
            for (int y = 0; y <= 9; y++) {

                output = output + x*y + "  ";

            }
            output = output + "\n";
        }
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,output);
    }
}
```